# Python: Compute surface area of a cylinder

Tags: python

This is what I have.  I need to print the surface area

```
def compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius, height):
    surface_area = 2 * math.pi * r * h + 2 * math.pi * math.pow(r, 2)
    return surface_area

radius = input("Radius of circle:")
radius = int(radius)
r = radius
height = input("Height of the cylinder:")
height = int(height)
h = height
```

Comment: Few comments 1) fix the indentation on your function , this is Python, indentation matters 2) where do you call your function to compute surface area ?

Comment: Please add a more specific question. What have you tried? What is working, what isn't?

Comment: Print function not working...I have:

Comment: print compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius,height)

Comment: print function not working? what version of python are you using?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @tommcbride Whiy is this relevant information missing from the question? There is an "edit" button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do it:

```
import math # You forgot this

def compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius, height):
    surface_area = 2 * math.pi * r * h + 2 * math.pi * math.pow(r, 2)
return surface_area

radius = input("Radius of circle:")
radius = int(radius)
r = radius
height = input("Height of the cylinder:")
height = int(height)
h = height

print compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius,height)
```

The above code will output the surface area of the cylinder based on radius and height, assuming the formula above is correct.

Comment: getting an error on the print function...that's where i'm going wrong somewhere.

Comment: @tommcbride:  If you are using Python 3 or greater, use `print (compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius,height))`

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius, height):
    surface_area = 2 * math.pi * radius * height + 2 * math.pi * math.pow(radius, 2)
    return surface_area


radius = int(input("Radius of circle:"))
#take this out "radius = int(radius)" and you save a line
#take this out an you save a line "r = radius"
height = int(input("Height of the cylinder:"))
# take this out and you save a line "height = int(height) "
#h = height
print(compute_surface_area_cylindar(radius,height))
```